# Calculate rolling price change in a dataframe, based on pairs of dates in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a function that calculates the daily change of a trade position between an entry and exit date (with corresponding entry and exit prices).

I have two dataframes:

Daily prices of the traded asset:

```
daily_prices_df:

Date        Close       
2014-01-02  885.0   
2014-01-03  880.0   
2014-01-06  873.0   
2014-01-07  871.0   
2014-01-08  870.0   
2014-01-09  862.0   
2014-01-10  861.0   
2014-01-13  850.0   
2014-01-14  862.0   
2014-01-15  859.0
```

A ordered dataframe of trades, whose records are entry-exit pairs, in the order entry date, entry price, exit date, exit price:

```
trades_df:
Date            Price
0   2014-11-18  495.7
1   2014-11-24  484.2
2   2014-11-26  474.1
3   2014-12-31  507.9
4   2015-01-05  495.9
5   2015-02-05  456.2
6   2015-02-24  461.5
7   2015-03-06  415.4
8   2015-03-31  368.5
9   2015-04-30  375.6
```

I need a function that can calculate the daily value of the trade with respect to the current asset price between the trade entry date, and the exit date.

I have tried a brute force method of iterating over each row of each dataframe with `df.iterrows()` and comparing the dates, but my logic doesn't seem to quite work out currently as I need to iterate in pairs for the trades data, and individually for the curves?

**Expected outcome:**
A column that shows the difference, for each day, between the trade entry price and the current price:

```
entry_date_1 = trades_df.loc[0]
exit_date_1 = trades_df.loc[1]

daily_prices_df



Date        Close   Price_Diff
2014-11-18  496.0   1
2014-11-19  484.0   -11
2014-11-20  487.0   8
2014-11-21  495.0   0
2014-11-24  484.0   -11
2014-11-25  470.0   -25
```

All help gratefully received, thank you

Comment: The sample of ```trade_df``` does no match the description of it: whose records are entry-exit pairs, in the order entry date, entry price, exit date, exit price.

Comment: Apologies, `trade_df`reads as: first row is entry date, entry price and the succeeding row is exit date, exit price.